# WP7 selection control

Tags: .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Does anybody know what type of control is used in WP7 Settings > Theme > Background?

Answer (score 1):

This control is a ListPicker.

There is no official equivalent control available but, Alex Yakhnin has created a version. There are [details on his blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/priozersk/creating-list-picker-for-wp7).

**Update:**
There is now a ListPicker in the [Silverlight Toolkit for Window Phone](https://web.archive.org/web/20180126142154/http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/55034). If you used the one that Alex created you should [migrate to the one in the toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/priozersk/migrate-pickerbox-and-listpicker-to-sl-toolkit).

Answer (score 1):

[ListPicker is out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/delay/mo-controls-mo-controls-mo-controls-announcing-the-second-release-of-the-silverlight-for-windows-phone-toolkit)

​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 0):

[Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/52297) ContextMenu

Comment: No. It's not a ContextMenu. You can see a context menu on the application list screen when you hold down on an item and the options to 'Pin to Start' and 'Uninstall' are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

It is a ListPicker control. There is a ListPicker control in the toolkit. You can also check the Telerik ListPicker control for Windows Phone 7 here - http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone.aspx

Comment: You might want to read the FAQ, especially the part about self-advertisement.